# I am trying to merge two datasets but the generated dataframe is empty?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, dataset

I am trying to merge my news dataset with my stock price dataset by date. When I merge them the code works but the returning dataframe is empty.

This is my code:

```
ddata['Date'] = ddata['Date'].astype(str)
cdata['Date'] = cdata['Date'].astype(str)
mdata = pd.merge(ddata, cdata, on ='Date')
```

This is what is returned:

[image]

Sample of my news dataset: [image]

Sample of my S&P 500 dataset: [image]

Thank you for the help :)

Comment: convert both dates into datetime or in same format then merge

Comment: How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the column `Date` of your dataframes in datetime:

```
cdata['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(cdata['Date'])
ddata['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(ddata['Date'])

mdata = pd.merge(ddata, cdata, on ='Date')
```

I think it's better to compare `datetime64` instead of `object` (just my personal opinion)

Comment: Hi, when I try running your code I get error ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and datetime64[ns] columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat. Any ideas?

Comment: @user16561849. I updated my answer. Could you try it, please?